# Calculate $R$, the radius of the circumscribed circle of the triangle $ABC$ according to $BC$.

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

*question*

Let be the triangle $ABC$ in which $BC=a$ and

> $\frac{1}{\tan^2A+\tan A+1}+\frac{1}{ctg^2A+ctgA+1}\leq\frac{2}{3}$.

Calculate $R$, the radius of the triangle's circumscribed circle $ABC$ according to $a$.

*my idea*

I first thought that we could write $R=\frac{a}{2 \sin A}$ by the sine theorem.

Also we can write $\tan A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}$

Let $\tan A=x=> ctg A=\frac{1}{x}$

Then we have $\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}\leq \frac{2}{3}$

I don't know what to do forward. Maybe the cosine theorem would help. Or the equality $\sin^2 A+ \cos^2A=1$

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: I suggest to use LaTeX/MathJax notation for the trigonometric functions: `\sin`, `\cos`, `\tan`. Looks much nicer and makes it better readable because the spacing is automatically adjusted.

Comment: Do you need the circumscribed circle radius in terms of $a$?

Comment: @Sahaj Yes, you are right!

Comment: OK. Continuing with your approach:

$$x^2-2x+1 \le 0$$ (note that we can only do this since $x^2+x+1$ has a fixed sign, ie positive, for all real $x$)
$$(x-1)^2 \le 0$$
This is only possible when $x=1$, since all squares are non-negative. Since $\tan A = 1$, we find $A = 45^{\circ}$.

So the circumscribed circle has radius $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{a\sqrt{2}}{2}$.